# TeeChart error on server server

Tags: asp.net, teechart

I am having problems in implementing TeeCharts on server. Application was initially running on .Net3.5, but now I have migrated it to .Net4.0. I have got it working on my local machine but if I deploy it on server I get "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
" error.

My application on local is running on vs2013, .Net4.0.
I am deploying it on windows server 2012. Can anyone please help.

Stack Trace of error:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
Steema.TeeChart.FrAccessProvider.GetLicense(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions) +153
System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.ValidateInternalRecursive(LicenseContext context, Type type, Object instance, Boolean allowExceptions, License& license, String& licenseKey) +214
System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.Validate(Type type, Object instance) +49
Steema.TeeChart.Chart..ctor() +72
```

Steema.TeeChart.Web.WebChart..ctor() +111

Answer (score 1):

This probably indicates the TeeChart license is not correctly compiled into your application. Please read **tutorial 17** on how to set it up correctly for web applications. TeeChart for .NET tutorials can be found at [Steema's docs page](http://www.teechart.net/docs/) or with your TeeChart installation. You may also check correct license installation on your development machine following the steps I posted [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7677).

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have added Licenses.Licx file onto my server with Licenses details : 'Steema.TeeChart.Web.WebChart, TeeChart, Version=1.1.1864.22788, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8126276c77bdb7'                                                         as told in the tutorial, but I am still getting same error. Apologies if my question is very silly but I am not getting it... Pls help....

Comment: @user2186239 please check your developer design-time license is correctly installed on your development machine following the steps I posted at http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7677. If you have any problem with it please let us know where it occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was just my stupid mistake, I had not deployed **App_Licenses.dll** to server so TeeChart was not able get licence details. After deploying that dll its all working fine. Thanks for the support.